# Changes to a thermometer that would require the spacing of the division to be larger

Tags: thermodynamics, instrument

> A mercury-in-glass thermometer having a **larger bulb**, a **narrower capillary tube** and **more liquid** will need to have a larger space between the divisions for an accurate reading compared to other thermometers.

Quoted above is a paragraph extracted from my textbook, which does not tell us why having these properties requires the thermometer to have a larger scale spacing. How does having these (bolded) properties require the spacing to be greater?

Comment: 'The spacing" for a one degree interval will be greater.  If you change to half-degree or five-degrees-per-mark rulings, though, it's still a thermometer.

Answer (score 1):

The expansivity of the mercury doesn't change—for any given temperature change, the *percent* increase in mercury volume will be the same as for a "reference" thermometer with a smaller bulb, less mercury, and wider capillary tube. But that same *percent* increase in volume will result in a larger *absolute* increase in the larger thermometer (because there is more mercury to start with) and will result in a higher *absolute* length change in the capillary tube (because the tube is narrower, so can hold a smaller volume of mercury per unit length).

This means the same temperature change that will result in a lengthening of $X$ in the reference thermometer will result in a lengthening of **more than** $X$ in the thermometer in question, requiring gradations that are spaced farther apart to properly indicate the correct temperature change.

Answer (score 0):

The stress here is on the meaning to the word "accurate".

Suppose that a given liquid thermometer has *accurate* tick marks at 1, 2, 3, ... This means, when the level is EXACTLY at that tick mark, the temperature is EXACTLY that value. The change in tick mark spacing per change in temperature is EXACTLY 1 unit in length : 1 unit in temperature. This is the starting point for an (infinitely) accurate device.

In a thought experiment, decrease the radius of the tube where the liquid expands. Now, when the liquid is heated, it will expand further for the same temperature change. Why? Because the volume expansion coefficient for the liquid has not changed and, to expand in the same volume at a smaller radius, the liquid has to expand to a larger distance.

Now, the thermometer calibration is no longer EXACT at 1 : 1. Rather, it is >1  unit in length : 1 unit in temperature. Conversely, one tick mark could have a calibrated temperature change that is only expressible with a numerical value that has an infinite number of significant digits to be EXACT. To recover the accuracy, we must recalibrate the tick marks. The new tick marks must be spaced further apart compared to the original tick marks.